# Uma resposta rápida e depois vários "edits"

Tags: debate, edição, respostas

Como proceder com uma resposta que você deu de maneira "apressada" e depois precisa editar para colocar mais informações, etc...

Seria uma má prática editar a resposta seguidas vezes em um intervalo pequeno de tempo?

Comment: Vejo direto casos em que a pessoa posta uma resposta rapidamente, primeiro do que os outros, e depois corrige praticamente a resposta toda em cima das outras respostas subsequentes que estavam melhores.

Comment: Ou pior: responde com umas 3 linhas, e em poucos minutos a resposta vira uma enciclopédia. Dá impressão que o objetivo é atrair logo a atenção do AP, e depois aumentar a resposta 10x para atrair votos.

Comment: @dvd As vezes eu dou uma ou outra resposta sem citar a fonte. Mas mais por medo dos haters eu prefiro logo depois achar a fonte ou referência e incluir na resposta, principalmente em perguntas mais "genéricas" ou que tem mais base teórica do que prática. Eu particularmente tento dar respostas explicando as coisas e não só entregando o código, acho que por isso necessito bastante desses edits seguidos...

Comment: @dvd O que eu já reparei é que tem gente que edita resposta antigas sem motivo algum aparente, apenas para ela voltar para o Topo da lista de Perguntas Ativas, e o autor tentar ganhar mais uns votos na pergunta ou resposta... Eu prefiro não julgar, mas não concordo muito com a prática. Talvez o "Edite Sem Motivo" (Ex. mudar onde era 10px por 12px para levar a resposta para lista de Ativas) seja uma pior pratica do que os "Edits Consecutivos".

Comment: Nunca parei pra pensar nisso rs... até porque eu acesso as perguntas mais pelo link "Perguntas" do que pela página inicial.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Acho que o melhor é já tentar postar a resposta já pronta, mas...

- Sempre há casos onde depois de postar, você esquece aquele detalhe, e aquele outro, e mais aquele, e no final acaba praticamente reescrevendo tudo.
- Existe muito o problema "*fastest gun in the west*", onde o primeiro que postar uma resposta tende a ter mais visibilidade, a atrair mais votos e a reduzir a atenção dada a outras respostas subsequentes. Isso muitas vezes acaba induzindo outras pessoas que estão escrevendo essas resposta a postá-las ainda incompletas e terminar depois com edições.
- Às vezes, elaborar a resposta completa é algo demorado e complexo, e fazer um trabalho incremental acaba sendo melhor.
- Respostas incompletas podem atrair votos negativos.
- Uma resposta incompleta boa pode impedir que uma resposta completa e muito ruim acabe sendo aceita ou recebendo votos positivos de usuários mais ingênuos.
- Às vezes, uma resposta incompleta é melhor do que não ter resposta nenhuma.
- Respostas que sofrem múltiplas edições podem indicar que não são boas e que o autor delas está tentando remendá-la de diversas formas para tentar sustentá-la.
- Respostas que sofrem múltiplas edições podem indicar que o autor é detalhista e perfeccionista e preza pela qualidade do que posta.
- Tem gente que consegue pensar melhor na escrita da resposta ao fazê-la em partes ao invés de uma vez só. Tem gente que é o oposto.

Observe que eu listo tanto aspectos positivos quanto negativos.

Logo, não dá para se dizer que é má prática fazer isso e nem que é boa prática. Cada caso é um caso. Querendo ou não, a verdade é que existe um pouco de jogo de estratégia em quem responde perguntas capazes de atrair múltiplas respostas rapidamente. Assim sendo, postar uma resposta incompleta pode fazer parte dessa estratégia, seja por motivos escusos ou legítimos.

Obs: Nessa resposta mesmo, depois de submeter, acabei lembrando de algumas coisas e fiz algumas edições nela (ainda dentro do intervalo de 5 minutos). :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Vitor, tem vários pontos que eu tb estava me questionando. No meu caso acho que eu sou detalhista (e desatento rss), até comentário meu eu edito quando ainda da tempo rss.

Comment: Às vezes eu perco a paciência quando vejo uma resposta do Victor (sim, perco mesmo =D ), e espero uns dois ou três dias para ler a versão final. Ou então pergunto a ele no chat se ele terminou (fiz isso na resposta de construir um objeto em estado válido). Mas eu também cometo esse mal de muitas edições rápidas, como meu principal meio de entrada é o celular, acabo cometendo muitos erros do errador-ortográfico ou mesmo clico sem querer no botão `submit`, errando por menos de um polegar o botão `preview`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ainda bem que as minhas não sofrem desse problema :D :D :D

Comment: Acabei de cometer o _fastest gun in the west_, mas aparentemente não cometi muitos erros e não mandei submeter a resposta antes de ela estar "completa o suficiente" para o AP, na minha opinião. E, sim, se alguém tivesse postado uma resposta antes da minha, é bem capaz de eu revisar minha publicação inteira e ela sair de outro jeito, talvez até mais completa. Mas minhas intenções foram quase nobres, eu juro, era mais focado em ajudar a sanar a dúvida do AP do que outra coisa